# error while importing stackblue into eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

I have download the newest version of [android-stackblur][1] ,when I import stackblur into eclipse,every thing is ok,but there are some error report by eclipse.I don't know if other people have encountered.My problem is:
First,eclipse report three errors in the file StackBlur/src/blur.rs.
1.error: Non-root compute kernel blur_v() is not supported in SDK levels 11-15.

2.warning: implicit declaration of function 'rsSetElementAt_uchar4' is invalid in C99

3.error: Non-root compute kernel blur_h() is not supported in SDK levels 11-15

Second,can't find class "ScriptC_blur" in RSBlurProcess.java file.

And i saw that it pass param R.raw.blur ,but the file res/raw/blur is not exists in the project.

Can anyone give some help? Thanks very much!

because of i have no enough reputation to post images, the issue link on github is:
https://github.com/kikoso/android-stackblur/issues/16

Comment: Are you able to fix this issue?